# Python3:below is pre-defined stats_value(arr);Kindly help me with the solution

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import statistics
def stats_values(arr):
```

#Input : arr - Numpy array
#Output: Function must print the statistics of the array in the following order
#1. Mean
#2. Median
#3. Standard Deviation
#4. Variance
#5. Mode
#5. Inter-Quartile Range
#Note: All the answers must be of Float datatype.Round your answers to 2 digits.
#'''
#Write your code here

```
x1 = np.mean(arr)
print('%.1f'%x1)
x2 = np.median(arr)
print('%.1f'%x2)
x3 = np.std(arr, dtype = np.float32)
print('%.2f'%x3)
x5 = np.var(arr)
print('%.1f'%x5)
MODE = stats.mode(arr)
x4= MODE[0]
print('%.1f'%x4 )
Q1 = np.percentile(arr, 25, interpolation = 'midpoint')
Q3 = np.percentile(arr, 75, interpolation = 'midpoint')
IQR = Q3 - Q1
print('%.1f'%iqr )

if __]name__ == "__main__":
 array_num=[]
 n=int(input())
 for i in range(n):
    a=input()
    af=float(a)
    array_num.append(af)
arr=np.array(array_num)
stats_values(arr)
```

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#This is my code but it's not passing other other cases except one.below are arr[] values
#**Test case 0:**  [2. 2. 3. 5.]   --working
#**Test case 1:** [ 9.2 10.7  6.8  9.   3.4  5.7  5.7]
#**Test case 2:** [23.   34.   56.    2.3   4.5   4.5  67.   89.   89.   89.   89.   89.
#4.67  3.45  2.45  3.45  6.8   9.    2.45 56.6 ]
#**Test case 3:**** [23.   34.   56.    2.3   4.5   4.5  67.   89.   89.   89.   89.   89.
#4.67  3.45  2.45  3.45  6.8   9.    2.45 56.6  45.   45.   45.   45.
#45.   45.   56.   78.   89.   78.   90.   12.   34.   56.   78.   23.
#45.   67.   89.   89.  ]
```

Comment: What error are you getting , can you please attach your error in the question?

Answer (score 3):

All the test cases were executed successfully for the below code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import statistics
def stats_values(arr):
#Write your code here
from scipy import stats
from math import sqrt
print(round(np.mean(arr),2))
print(round(np.median(arr),2))
N = len(arr)
mu = sum(arr)/float(N)
diff_sq = [(i-mu)**2 for i in arr]
variance = sum(diff_sq)/float(N)
stdev = sqrt(sum(diff_sq)/float(N))
print(round(stdev,2))
print(round(variance,2))
print(float(stats.mode(arr)[0]))
arr.sort()
qa_third, qa_first = np.percentile(arr, [75 ,25])
iqr = qa_third - qa_first
print(round(iqr,2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
array_num=[]
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a=input()
    af=float(a)
    array_num.append(af)
arr=np.array(array_num)
stats_values(arr)
```